# Consequences of making an Async function synchronous

Tags: c#, async-await

*(I apologize in advance if some part/parts of the question are considered "too basic". I've done my research about async-await, but for me it is not an easy concept to grasp. Either that or I haven't found the right resources.)*

I've always read (or that is what I interpreted) that "the way to make an asynchornous call synchronous is to put 'await' in front of it".

So the code resulting from this statement is as shown in this simple code:

```
// CODE 1:
public void async MyFunction()
{
    await SomeFunctionAsync();
}
```

That is: 1) put `await` in front of the Async function, 2) put `async` in your function, because now it contains an `await`.

But in my experience sometimes behaves a bit "funnily". The symptoms I've noticed are that sometimes it behaves like a thread that escapes my control.

So the **first question** would be: what happens when you call `MyFunction()` and this function contains the `async` keyword? My understanding is that (confusingly enough) it should not be called `MyFunctionAsync()` because that is reserved for functions that return a `Task`.

...so the alternative that I've come up with (that seems to behave like a synchronous class consistently) is this type of code:

```
// CODE 2:
public void MyFunction()
{
    var task = SomeFunctionAsync();
    Task.WaitAll(task);
}
```

**Second question**: could someone explain the downsides (if any) of `CODE 2`?

Also, the implicit question is that I am interested in knowing about any misconception that I might have about the async-await pattern.

Comment: "what happens when you call MyFunction() and this function contains the async keyword?" It will execute asynchronously but you can't await it because it doesn't return a Task. That's why it seems to escape your control. In answer to your second question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've always read (or that is what I interpreted) that "the way to make an asynchornous call synchronous is to put 'await' in front of it".

Not at all. This is a *serial* way to call asynchronous code, but not a *synchronous* say. "Synchronous" means "blocking the current thread", and `await` won't block the current thread. However, "serial" means "do this before the next thing", and `await` will do that. For more information, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Using `await` is the most natural and common way to call an asynchronous method. Note that normally when you add an `async` to the method, you *should also change the return type* from `void` to `Task`. The compiler will guide you in this: if you just put the `await` in without the `async`, it will suggest the next change for you very explicitly.

> But in my experience sometimes behaves a bit "funnily". The symptoms I've noticed are that sometimes it behaves like a thread that escapes my control.

This is because your code is using `async void` and not `async Task`. `async void` is unnatural; you have no "control" because you're not returning a `Task`. The more natural approach is to make the method `async Task`, and `await` that task from *it's* callers, and so on. It is natural for `async` to "grow" through your stack like this - what we call "[async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)".

> So the first question would be: what happens when you call MyFunction() and this function contains the async keyword? My understanding is that (confusingly enough) it should not be called MyFunctionAsync() because that is reserved for functions that return a Task.

Your understanding regarding naming is correct. `MyFunction` is not a natural (`Task`-returning) asynchronous method.

`async void` methods are very strange and do not behave like normal `async` methods. Their odd behavior is one reason why I recommend to [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). But since you asked...

An `await` inside an `async void` method works just like an `await` in a regular `async` method (as I describe in my `async` intro): it will capture the current context (the current `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`, and resume executing the `async void` method in that context when the asynchronous operation completes. This is why it acts like a "thread outside your control" - it just resumes executing whenever it needs to. You have no way of detecting when it's complete because the method returned `void` instead of `Task`.

Exceptions are where things get even more weird. `async void` methods capture the current `SynchronizationContext` at the beginning of their execution, and if an exception escapes the `async void` method, it'll re-raise that exception on its captured `SynchronizationContext`. This generally causes a process-level crash.

> Second question: could someone explain the downsides (if any) of CODE 2?

It can easily cause a [deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog. It will also wrap any exceptions from the task in an `AggregateException`.

The bottom line is: don't block on asynchronous code. If you're going to block on it anyway, then why make it asynchronous in the first place? Any mixed blocking-and-async code should be considered technical debt of a rather high priority. There's no solution that works in all cases, but there are a variety of hacks that you can *temporarily* use while upgrading your code to be properly asynchronous; I describe them in an article on [brownfield async development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).